# How to put the image left side of input boxes Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

[This is what it looks like on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3xJa.png)

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VLampone/ebox7eer/)

They are far apart because I used pull-left and pull-right. I want them to be in center next to each other. I have tried Bootstrap columns and it didn't fix any issues. What is other possible solution?

```
    $('form').card({
   // container to render to
   container: '.card-wrapper',

   // input boxes to pull from
   formSelectors: {
     numberInput: 'input#number',
     expiryInput: 'input#expiry',
     cvcInput:  'input#cvc',
     nameInput:   'input#name'
  },

  // placeholders on the virtual card
  placeholders: {
    number: '•••• •••• •••• ••••',
    name: 'Full Name',
    expiry: '••/••',
    cvc: '•••'
  },
});
```

Comment: Please double check your fiddle link, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: hmm. what image?, and btw you don't need to copy paste jquery-ui css code into the css frame. you can add resources to Jsfiddle by supplying a link to the file.

Comment: check the fiddle its not working

Comment: The credit card image. Fiddle works fine for me.